# Custom output stream that acts like std::cout

Tags: c++, stream

I wrote a simple output stream object that from the user point of view should act exactly like the classic `std::cout`. I need it because I want to customize the printing behavior of my program.

Can you review my code? Do you see anything wrong in it?

**File Utils.h:**

```
namespace Utils
{
   static std::ostream& Log;
}
```

**File Utils.cpp:**

```
struct MyStream : std::ostream, std::streambuf
{
public:
   MyStream() : std::ostream(this) { }
   std::streambuf::int_type overflow(std::streambuf::int_type c)
   {
      std::cout << c;
      // My custom operations
      return 0;
   }
};
std::ostream& Utils::Log = MyStream();
```

Comment: How do you want to customize the behavior?

Comment: Temporaries cannot be bound to non const lvalue references, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Deduplicator It doesn't really matter, I need to collect data sent to the output stream and copy it to other destinations.

Comment: @Incomputable what do you mean? It compiles fine

Comment: If you want to have multiple destinations for an output-stream, you need a custom stream-buffer, but can use a standard ostream.

Comment: It's confusing that you call your instance `Log` but that you want it to use `std::cout` and not `std::clog`.

Answer (score 6):

### Construction

The construction of a `MyStream` object will proceed like this:

1. Construct `std::ostream` part with pointer to not-yet-constructed `std::streambuf` part.
2. Construct `std::streambuf` part.
3. Construct `MyStream` part.

Thus, suggestion: Reorder inheritance list like this:

`struct MyStream : std::streambuf, std::ostream`

### `override` specifier

Nitpick: Add `override` specifier for `overflow()` function:

`std::streambuf::int_type overflow(std::streambuf::int_type c) override`

### `struct` vs `class`

Another nitpick. I'm noticing that you are using `struct` instead of `class`. It is subjective, but I like to distinguish between `struct` and `class` like this:

- If the resulting object will *mostly* be used by calling its methods - it's a `class`.
- If the resulting object will *mostly* be used by accessing its fields - it's a `struct`.

Thus, for `MyStream` I would use `class` instead of `struct`. But, as I said, it is subjective.